# How can the same app with the same database (with the same content) generate different HTML on Heroku and locally? Error in pre-compilation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, precompile

The app works on Heroku except that it's supposed to show a graph, with gon and cytoscape js, but doesn't. There are no error messages.

The only significant difference in the HTML is that in production, all the javascript and stylesheet-files are precompiled:

Production:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-97fedf3d6ebadf9658f179ce8a751e3ed05d1aa3bf6ce6be192e397b824e7f74.css" />
<script src="/assets/application-d5a91369fc9a95afb2281d718e463b03184e0ece461c52b2d8c78e63b5ef16a4.js"></script>
```

Local:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/select2.self-896365bdffeaf8e35a12caad065cc092cfcb4f7a36ad77eb1343fa6f6f40cc66.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/select2-bootstrap.self-7da9a1fdf6150ac9fb6849734104aaba844871ff119da43ea0ceccc930c476af.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-9d1d421547202855000cc25c86f69148522c38ed15a4de25e485df0c264540b7.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap.self-603f330c29af013305325569c8c75d03d688963abd8cde4fffec17b5ce417bfb.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites.self-556e1741ff6d22f63fe0be609679c8f06ffc45eabc31836b6b785475bb283b84.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.self-f5a90d20e5090d64763dcfad94d947343b9898d7a030bb466e9247e00ca06c27.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/medium-editor/medium-editor.self-513b85b7e3f9f288dadfa41bab0c8ba717f1279b13595f2dc77b54bebfe3431f.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/medium-editor/themes/beagle.self-534d90e3c85b8c27175857dd3bab276778312301f1f74dd99e03628ee8c541c2.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/articles.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/relations.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds.self-f5864251a4ff9b509f17052c56a2d24456178589b1a90a9f5b55db97cb05b1bc.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/users.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-8944eaf3f9a2615ce7c830a810ed630e296633063af8bb7441d5702fbe3ea597.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/articles.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-fdc98dee79ee88255e10cac6caa91338165cb76cf0d263744d8d90011fc2ef8f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-69fddfcddf4fdef9828648f9330d6ce108b93b82b0b8d3affffc59a114853451.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/octal.self-364e41a86713de4f2a1d22b511f99ca79eef4059e839c02b099ca2ee289884d6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/relations.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/medium-editor.self-a4f361c2dcb6e54ca3400cb6cb9de9b0a38eddd36c417cd31f8add83ae7c422c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/select2.self-1c5f606a53ee7fae6f11ffa522c8ccf8076493d9d5b5ae25564bd853679f48d2.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/auto_select2/static_select2.self-d4bd2ab2573f1ebb1355356089a29f4a863eeac5fe2ab8e71dc27c8c3faeb57d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/auto_select2/ajax_select2.self-a9fcebdf470e2df0f8263df8f5d204a4f4a9e4bbde5299d8074af377f9dd233c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/auto_select2/multi_ajax_select2_value_parser.self-b9df3fd4ad3813e60541ffb5bd90f7a2308d28bd590ba55e8e6894a62f106844.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-f74b421b6b3f8f87122d354a558aa64b553aee34b1bf06a7515456271b87a3c5.js?body=1"></script>
```

So the root here must be some problem with the asset pre-compilation?

I tried restarting Heroku and using Puma as Webserver on Heroku, but that didn't make a difference. (Maybe it's the default anyway? Couldn't figure this out.)

These are the gems that are only loaded in development:

```
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
```

There are no gems that are only loaded in production.

Comment: Don't you think it's a data issue? on your computer, your rails project is running in the development environment against your local database! while on Heroku you are running production environment against the production database.

Comment: I generated the content of both databases with the same script, and the HTML is the same other then javascript and stylesheet-embeds I showed. I also run a few things like "Article.all.length" and "Relation.all.length" in the console both locally and on heroku and got the same result.